# How to enable a WordPress installation and a Mediawiki installation on the same subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I have a subdomain that has a WordPress installation on its root (e.g. `https://sub.domain.com`). This opens the WordPress frontpage.

Then I installed a Mediawiki installation in a directory called `w`, and renamed it using the ShortURL method [specified here in this Mediawiki documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL) and added the necessary `.htaccess` adjustments to make the Mediawiki installation uses this url structure: `https://sub.domain.com/wiki`.

Then I added another Mediawiki installation in another folder called `typ` and followed the same steps detailed above.

I wanted to have 2 Mediawiki installations for different purposes. They are not linked to each other.

However, after the Mediawiki installations, the WordPress took over, and when I try to access the `/wiki` urls, I get a `404 not found` from the WordPress.

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?typing(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/typ/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/typ/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]



</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

The only way to get the Mediawiki installations to show is to comment out the WordPress lines, like this:

```
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

My question is: Is there a way to get all the installations working at the same time? so `https://sub.domain.com` opens the WordPress installation, and `https://sub.domain.com/wiki` and `https://sub.domain.com/typing` open the MEdiawiki installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to move the Mediawiki lines up the `.htaccess` file, remove the duplicates.

Here is the final code that worked:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?typing(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/typ/index.php [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteRule ^/?typ/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/typ/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^/?typ/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/typ/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]


</IfModule>
```